# Port R into Cuda

Tags: r, parallel-processing, data-analysis

I have a function `fun1` written in `R` that takes a long time to run.   I need to run said function a large number of times.

I have done some reading about running `R` programs on graphics cards and have only come up with a few packages that can run very specific functions (most matrix manipulation).

My question is: Is there a way to run `fun1` or any user written function, on a graphics card (parallelized for speed).  Such as a CUDA interpreter for `R` that could be installed, or maybe a way to compile `R` functions for cuda so that all I would have to do would be to write a little bit of `Cuda/C` to excecute my function originally written in `R`?

Anything and everything is helpful

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no converter for any generic function to CUDA or OPENCL for that matter.  I would love to be proven wrong as it would be a tremendous asset.

The structure of functions for GPU is very different from normal CPU programming.  So there is no CUDA interpreter for R.  If you want something in R run on a GPU you need to:

1. Write your desired function in CUDA
2. Compile it with NVCC
3. Link it to some additional C++ code (likely using Rcpp).

You can look at how this has been accomplished with most of the available R GPU packages.

My unreleased package using CUDA can be seen [here](https://github.com/gpuRcore/gpuRcuda).  If you are interested in using OpenCL, my currently released, and more actively developed, package [gpuR](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gpuR/index.html) may be of interest to you.  I am currently working on an interface to allow users to use custom OpenCL.

Comment: Good and very gentle answer. But don't be shy and do link to yours.  Working examples are good!